# Incremental Variable for Groups of SharePoint List Items

Tags: list, variables, sharepoint, workflow

I am having issues visualizing and implementing an incremental variable for groups of list items as they are added to a custom SharePoint 2010 list.

Essentially, I want to give users the ability to add "n" number of items as part of a "batch" of list items. A consistent, visible "batch number" will be added to each list item they add until they select a "process batch" button, which will ultimately run a workflow and hopefully change the batch number to "[BatchNumber]+1".

I know this requires using a workflow in a variable, but I am having trouble conceptualizing and implementing such a workflow solution where the batch number remains consistent until the user is ready to "process" the "batch" (all of the list items they have added).

Can anyone assist in detailing how this workflow would look and how I would go about creating it?